# How to insert into MongoDB array

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my collection:
[image]

What Im trying to do is to insert a new "departamento" using JAVA, but when I do it, it is created as a new object. 
[image]

And this is what Im doing in java:
[image]
Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, there is a function called update that has two parameters first the query of the element you want to update, send some configuration to update using the operator $push

```
db.departamentos.update({"titulo": "nombre"}, { $push: { "departamento": {"ubicacion": "Barcelona", "nombre": "nombre2"}}})
```

Take a look from MongoShell

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Im trying this but it is not working. db.colecion.update({"departamentos":{ "titulo": "DATOS DE LA TABLA DEPART"}}, { $push: {"departamentos": {"departamento": {"ubicacion": "Barcelona", "nombre": "nombre2"}}}})

Comment: Okey sorry i though departamentos where the collection but is not, right?

Comment: It's fine it worked now, now I have to try it on Java, thank you!

Comment: Try this

db.colecion.updateOne({"departamentos.titulo": "DATOS DE LA TABLA"}, { $push: { "departamentos.departamento": {"ubicacion": "Barcelona", "nombre": "nombre2"}}})

Comment: I did it! Thank you very much!